# Protecting individual pages in memory allocated by VirtualAlloc

Tags: c, winapi, memory

Let's say I have allocated several pages of continuous memory using `VirtualAlloc()` from `0x06000000` to `0x06010000` (That's 16 4KB pages) with `PAGE_READWRITE` protection. But after a while, I want to make a single page in that region of memory executable. After reading the msdn documentation for `VirtualProtect()`, I'm confused if this is possible or not. In linux, it is with `mprotect`.

Visual example of what I'm trying to do:

```
     +-------------------------------------------------------+
     | Commited memory with a single VirtualAlloc call (RW-) |
     +-------------------------------------------------------+
     ↑                                                       ↑
0x06000000                                              0x06010000
```

And I want to change the protection to this (Not to scale):

```
     +------------------+-----------+------------------------+
     |      (RW-)       |   (RWX)   |         (RW-)          |
     +------------------+-----------+------------------------+
     ↑                  ↑           ↑                        ↑
0x06000000         0x06003000  0x06004000               0x06010000
```

Would I be allowed to this with a `VirtualProtect()` call like this?

```
VirtualProtect(0x06003000, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
```

I currently don't have access to a Windows system to test this, that's why I'm asking it on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VirtualProtect(0x06003000, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);` is correct for an already allocated/committed block of memory of 0x1000 bytes starting at 0x06003000.

Comment: So `VirtualProtect()` wouldn't mind if I'm changing the protection of a specific page rather than the entire range `VirtualAlloc()` allocated?

Comment: ...and I just checked the ReactOS kernel source, and there's a function called `MmSplitRegion()` that splits a region `VirtualAlloc()` allocated in to several regions so it's okay to do

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are pretty clear:

> The region of affected pages includes all pages containing one or more
>   bytes in the range from the lpAddress parameter to (lpAddress+dwSize).
>   This means that a 2-byte range straddling a page boundary causes the
>   protection attributes of both pages to be changed.

Note that you can only change the protection on committed pages (MEM_RESERVE only reserves space in the process's virtual address space)

The following quote does not apply to your specific question but you should keep it in mind if you change your design:

> All pages in the specified region must be within the same reserved
>   region allocated when calling the VirtualAlloc or VirtualAllocEx
>   function using MEM_RESERVE. The pages cannot span adjacent reserved
>   regions that were allocated by separate calls to VirtualAlloc or
>   VirtualAllocEx using MEM_RESERVE.